# RailsAdmin: how to render a different model index from a custom action

Tags: rails-admin

On my website I have users that can apply to jobs, creating a candidacy in my database.

In the jobs index of the admin, I created a custom action so next to each job I have a button that I can press to access the index of the candidacies for this job.

Except that this custom action doesn't work:

```
  class Candidacies < RailsAdmin::Config::Actions::Base
      RailsAdmin::Config::Actions.register(self)
      register_instance_option :member? do true end
      register_instance_option :only do [Job] end
      register_instance_option :link_icon do 'fa fa-users' end
      register_instance_option :controller do
          proc do
              @id = params[:id]
              @objects = Candidacy.where(job_id: @id)
              render :index
          end
      end
  end
```

I load all the candidacies for the job but when I try to redirect to the candidacies index, RailsAdmin tries to load the job index but with candidacies instead of jobs so it lead to an error 500 because candidacies and job do not share the same fields.

Do someone knows how can I load the index candidacies with the candidacies of a specific job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a jobs filter on the candidacies index and then build a link to the candidacies with that job pre-filtered.

First add the job field to the candidacies admin config

```
  rails_admin do
    list do
      field :job do
        filterable true
      end
    end
  end
```

Then i believe the url would look like something this:

```
"/admin/candidacy?model_name=candidacy&utf8=✓&f[job][52801][o]=is&f[job][52801][v]=#{job.id}"
```

You can get it from your browser filtering the view with the UI and decoding the url with a [tool like this](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)

So when your users click the link they'll be taken to the candidacies with job prefiltered.

You can then modify your action to redirect instead to the url of render the :index